# Programmatically adding metadata to a video file

Tags: video, metadata, vlc, video-encoding, video-embedding

I wanted to write an online parser that would write/change metadata to a video and hence providing information about the video content like the Proper title, List of Actors, Director and Producer e.t.c. I would like to use that for indexing purposes later. I found certain softwares like MetaX, EasyTag e.t.c. that would allow adding metadata maually. Is there any way to retrieve video information online and add that to the video file programmatically.

Comment: i dont think anything like this for online stuff is there as there will be tough issues in validating the changes etc and moreover if the file is like mp, you need to update the atoms in the different boxes which is bit tricky. If you have the particular kind of file, you can make a service to update metadata online.

Comment: Can I do it only for mp4 or something?

Comment: no, any sort of MPEG data you can or the stream also like the MpegTS as well.